# I had the error occurred that the stock can't be read after five minutes

Tags: python, message, stock

When I run this program and wait five minutes, I get the below error, but I'm a bit unfamiliar with what's going on here. Does anyone know any methods to fix the above error in order to make the program run successfully? Is there anything in particular that I'm doing wrong? I really appreciate any help.

## Code:

```
    import twstock
    import time
    import requests
    
    def LINE_Notify(token,msg):
        headers = {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer '+token,
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        }
        payload = {'message':msg}
        notify = requests.post('https://notify-api.line.me/api/notify',headers=headers,params=payload)
        return notify.status_code
    
    def sendline(mode,realprice,counterLine,token):
        print('Current Stock price: ' + str(realprice))
        if mode == 1:
            message = 'The current stock price is ' + str(realprice) + '. You can sell out now'
    
        else:
            message = 'The current stock price is ' + str(realprice) + '. You can buy in now'
        code = LINE_Notify(token,message)
        if code == 200:
            counterLine += 1
            print('The message is sent '+ str(counterLine)+' times')
        else:
            print('Failed to send!')
        return counterLine
    
    
    
    token ='###'
    counterLine = 0
    counterError = 0
    
    print('The program starts now')
    while True:
        realdata = twstock.realtime.get('2317')
        if realdata['success']:
            realprice = realdata['realtime']['latest_trade_price']
            if float(realprice) >= 80:
                counterLine = sendline(1,realprice,counterLine,token)
            elif float(realprice) <= 60:
                counterLine = sendline(2,realprice,counterLine,token)
            if counterLine >= 3:
                print('Program ends')
                break
        else:
            print('Stock number 2317 data cannot be read: '+ realdata['rtmessage'])
            counterError += 1
            if counterError >= 3:
                print('Program ends')
                break
        for i in range(300):
            time.sleep(1)
```

## Error:

```
      Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\Dominic\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\urllib3\contrib\pyopenssl.py", line 488, in wrap_socket
        cnx.do_handshake()
      File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\OpenSSL\SSL.py", line 1934, in do_handshake
        self._raise_ssl_error(self._ssl, result)
      File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\OpenSSL\SSL.py", line 1671, in _raise_ssl_error
        _raise_current_error()
      File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\OpenSSL\_util.py", line 54, in exception_from_error_queue
        raise exception_type(errors)
    OpenSSL.SSL.Error: [('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')]
    
    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
    
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\Dominic\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 670, in urlopen
        httplib_response = self._make_request(
      File "C:\Users\Dominic\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 381, in _make_request
        self._validate_conn(conn)
      File "C:\Users\Dominic\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 976, in _validate_conn
        conn.connect()
      File "C:\Users\Dominic\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 361, in connect
        self.sock = ssl_wrap_socket(
      File "C:\Users\Dominic\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 377, in ssl_wrap_socket
        return context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
      File "C:\Users\Dominic\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\urllib3\contrib\pyopenssl.py", line 494, in wrap_socket
        raise ssl.SSLError("bad handshake: %r" % e)
    ssl.SSLError: ("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')])",)
    
    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
    
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\Dominic\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 439, in send
        resp = conn.urlopen(
      File "C:\Users\Dominic\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 724, in urlopen
        retries = retries.increment(
      File "C:\Users\Dominic\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 439, in increment
        raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
    urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='mis.twse.com.tw', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /stock/index.jsp (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')])")))
    
    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
    
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "E:/Python/Python Data Science/Ch11 LINE/linestock.py", line 37, in <module>
        realdata = twstock.realtime.get('2317')
      File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\twstock\realtime.py", line 92, in get
        data = get_raw(stocks) if not mock else twstock.mock.get(stocks)
      File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\twstock\realtime.py", line 71, in get_raw
        req.get(SESSION_URL, proxies=get_proxies())
      File "C:\Users\Dominic\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 543, in get
        return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\Dominic\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 530, in request
        resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\Dominic\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 665, in send
        history = [resp for resp in gen] if allow_redirects else []
      File "C:\Users\Dominic\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 665, in <listcomp>
        history = [resp for resp in gen] if allow_redirects else []
      File "C:\Users\Dominic\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 237, in resolve_redirects
        resp = self.send(
      File "C:\Users\Dominic\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 643, in send
        r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\Dominic\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 514, in send
        raise SSLError(e, request=request)
    requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='mis.twse.com.tw', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /stock/index.jsp (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')])")))
```

Answer (score 0):

`twstock.realtime.get('2317')` have max requests per time. You send too many requests to the site. See the last error: "Max retries exceeded". Try adding more time to the sleep or check out if the "twstock" docs or the website (mis.twse.com.tw) API have info about it.

Also, You don't need the loop for the sleep. You can do instead: `time.sleep(300)`

Comment: No, "Max retries exceeded" comes from Requests/urllib, not the remote server.

Comment: The error is in line 37, `realdata = twstock.realtime.get('2317')`, right? So, probably `twstock` is using Requests/urllib, which mean that is from the remote server. Also, the source code of this function is using `requests`.

Comment: No, it's requests/urllib _retrying_, not the server telling the user they've tried too many times. That'd be something like a `requests.HTTPError 429`.

Comment: There is still error if I don't use while loop for ```time.sleep(300)```

Comment: First, the sleep not really mater. I just suggest a cleaner way. Secondly, I think the ape of the stock have a rate limit, that maybe why it stop working after five minutes.

Comment: So how can I set the limit of stock?

Comment: You may try to make web automation using selenium